# proper hibernate mapping for @lob in Hibernate pojo. we are using hibernate mapping. can you please tell me equivalent for @lob annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, bytea

We are using hibernate mapping. In hibernate configuration file we have given type="blob" and pojo class getBlob and setBlob methods we have. Apart from this we need to have @lob right. what  is equivalent for lob in hibernate mapping

```
@Override
public Hospital  getHospital(long hospId, String hospitalName) {
    Hospital hos= hibernateTemplate.find("from Hospital
    hos where hos.id = ? and hos.name = ? ", hospId,hospitalName);          
}
@Transactional
public void saveHospital(Hosipital hos) {
    Blob blob = Hibernate.getLobCreator(hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()).createBlob(hos.getContent());
    hos.setHospitalImage(blob);
    hibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate("Hospital", hos);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my model I'm using the following:

```
@Lob
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Column(name = "CONTENUTO_BLOB", nullable = true)
public Blob getContenutoBlob()
{
    return contenutoBlob;
}
```

The annotation `@Lob` indicates that it's a Lob column; the `@Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)` indicates to load the entity without loading the Lob in memory; you can access to the lob only when you really need

**UPDATE**

Long time I don't use XML but if I'm not wrong you may use something like this:

```
 <property name="contenutoBlob" type="org.hibernate.type.BinaryType" lazy="true">
 </property>
```

**UPDATE 2**

I never used `hibernateTemplate` in any case also by using hibernateTemplate you can access to the hibernate session
Usually I do the following:

***Save Blob method***

```
public void saveAllegato(InputStream fileIn, long lunghezza) throws DbException
    {
        //Dai test effettuati, quando siamo col portale attivo bisogna non chiudere
        //mai lo stream
        boolean closeStream = false;
        try
        {
            //sf is the SessionFactory
            Session sessione = sf.getCurrentSession();
            Blob blob = null;
            if (null != fileIn)
            {
                blob = Hibernate.getLobCreator(sessione).createBlob(fileIn, lunghezza);
            }
            AllegatoModel entity = new AllegatoModel();
            //Set the other fields
            if( blob != null )
            {

                entity.setContenutoBlob(blob);
            }
            // Save object
            sessione.saveOrUpdate(entity);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            String message = "Errore nel salvataggio della entity " + entity + "; " + e.getMessage();
            logger.error(message, e);
            throw new PinfGpDbException(message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (fileIn != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    fileIn.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    //Stampo lo stacktrace solo quando il log ha livello di debug
                    if( logger.isDebugEnabled() )
                    {

                        logger.debug("Errore nella chiusura del file input stream ", e);
                    }
                    else if( logger.isWarnEnabled() )
                    {
                        logger.debug("Errore nella chiusura del file input stream; "+e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

***GET BLOB METHOD***

```
public void writeAllegatoFile(Long id, OutputStream out) throws PinfGpDbException
{
    StopWatch sw = new StopWatch("SCRITTURA FILE CON ID ["+id+"] SU OUTPUTSTREAM");
    InputStream is = null;
    try
    {
        sw.start("RECUPERO FILE DA DB");
        DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(AllegatoModel.class);
        criteria.add(Property.forName("id").eq(id));
        ProjectionList pl = Projections.projectionList();
        pl.add(Projections.property("contenutoBlob"), "contenutoBlob");
        pl.add(Projections.property("id"), "id");
        criteria.setProjection(pl);
        criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(AllegatoModelBlobDto.class));
        Session sessione = sf.getCurrentSession();
        List<AllegatoModelBlobDto> result = criteria.getExecutableCriteria(sessione).list();
        sw.stop();
        StopWatchUtils.printStopWatchInfo(sw, logger, false, "QUERY ESEGUITA CORRETTAMENTE. RECORD TROVATI "+result.size()+" RECUPERATO CORRETTAMENTE");
        if (result.size() > 1)
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Impossibile proseguire trovati " + result.size() + "record per l'ID " + id);
        }
        AllegatoModelBlobDto theObj = result.get(0);
        if (theObj != null)
        {
            Blob contenuto = theObj.getContenutoBlob();

            if (contenuto != null)
            {
                sw.start("SCRITTURA FILE SU OUTPUT STREAM");
                is = contenuto.getBinaryStream();
                IOUtils.copy(is, out);
                sw.stop();
                StopWatchUtils.printStopWatchInfo(sw, logger, false, "SCRITTURA FILE TERMINATA CORRETTAMENTE");
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        String message = "Errore nel recupero dell'allegato con ID " + id;
        logger.error(message, e);
        throw new PinfGpDbException(message, e);
    }
    finally
    {
        if(sw.isRunning())
        {
            sw.stop();
            StopWatchUtils.printStopWatchInfo(sw, logger, true, "POSSIBILE ERRORE NELLA SCRITTURA DEL FILE");
        }
        if( is != null )
        {
            try
            {
                is.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Stampo lo stacktrace solo quando il log ha livello di debug
                if( logger.isDebugEnabled() )
                {

                    logger.debug("Errore nella chiusura del file input stream ", e);
                }
                else if( logger.isWarnEnabled() )
                {
                    logger.debug("Errore nella chiusura del file input stream; "+e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        if( out != null )
        {
            try
            {
                out.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Stampo lo stacktrace solo quando il log ha livello di debug
                if( logger.isDebugEnabled() )
                {

                    logger.debug("Errore nella chiusura dell'output stream ", e);
                }
                else if( logger.isWarnEnabled() )
                {
                    logger.debug("Errore nella chiusura dell'output stream; "+e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am not using hibernate annotations. Assume you are using hibernate mapping,how you can acheive @lob in hibernate mapping?

Comment: Thanks for your update. But i am not using binary type. I am using type blob as shown here.<property name="hospitalImage" column="hospital_image" type="blob" /> in postgres

Comment: There is no blob type in HIbernate. The type `org.hibernate.type.BinaryType` tells hibernate to manage this property as a binary object; then you in your ode can use java.sql.Blob or the implementation of your RDBMS

Comment: we are using type="java.sql.Blob" . Binary type having limitations in image handling.if you use blob type it extends up to 2gb in saving to database.Binary type wont extend up to 2gb. As per postgres documentations.

Comment: at this point try to use `type=org.hibernate.type.BlobType` you can give a look to all hibernate types here https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/type/package-summary.html

Comment: can you please check the below link. If i am wrong correct me.http://www.e2college.com/subjects/java_programming/tutorials/hibernate_native_api_with_mysql_tutorial/hibernate_entity_table_mapping_types.html

Comment: The link is showing to you the "mapping" between Hibernate types and DB types. In your case you want to handle a java.sql.Blob object by using hibernate. So you must tell hibernate: my dear hibernate this field is a Blob. How can you tell hibernate this? You can by using the right hibernate type. So by using the XML fragment I showed you are saying: this is a property to persist and it is a Blob

Comment: Okay. If will use org.hibernate.type.BlobType in xml mapping. Then will it be equivalent to @Lob annotation. Is there any other stuff i need to do in my pojo class (Mapping class file for Blob setter and getter)i.e., getBlob and setBlob methods enough to get Blob object

Comment: As far as I know it should be sufficient what I wrote no other stuffs in your pojo... let me know if it works....

Comment: it is working but still having some doubts. If blob object i am using in different table then it is working. In the same table if i use blob then it is not working. Blob.getlength() coming as zero. Hospital table i have a column hospital_image. when i want to fetch the image by using hospital object then it is not working. Blob.lenght() coming zero. So i can't able to write .

Comment: int dataSize;
        InputStream is = mainImageBlob.getBinaryStream();
        try {
            while ((dataSize = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
                baos.write(buf, 0, dataSize);
            }
        } . For suppose if i create a new table called file table and i have a relation like this. One hospital having many images. Then blob.getlength() is working fine. I dont know why it is not working with in the same object. I need to use a different transaction to get the image if i use the same transaction with in the same table?

Comment: try to update your question by adding your code. In any case as far as I know you should be inside hibernate session to operate with Blob

Comment: I  have updated my code. saving hospital object is working fine. I can see the hospital_image (oid)  column got some numeric values. Where as while fetching the hospital object. i am not using any session or Transaction. Do you want me to use any session or Transaction. Please help me here. I dont have any idea why it is not working.

Comment: @Ravi I guess this is off topic respect to the question.. in any case see the update 2 where i wrote what i usually do to save and write Blobs

Answer (score 0):

Use the `basic` tag and add the `lob` tag inside:

```
    <basic name="lobcolumn">
        <column name="lob_column"/>
        <lob/>
    </basic>
```

Comment: So in pojo class we need to getBlob and setBlob ? No need to use setLOb and getLob?

Comment: <property name="hospitalImage" column="hospital_image" type="blob" />

Comment: I am using postgres db. Column datatype is oid

Answer (score 0):

type is blob. it maps to hibernate pojo with Blob data type.Both will match and it saves your image as well.

In hbm.xml u

property name="contentualblob" type="blob"